# Function split in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, split

[Duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c?rq=1)

Is there a function in c++ that does the same that the split function in C?

I wrote this code

```
std::string str[] =line.split(";");
```

But a call to split is not recognized.

Comment: What is the `line`? There is `QString::split()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `qt` solution :

```
#include <QStringList>
//...

QStringList L = line.split( ";" , QString::SkipEmptyParts );
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^optional
```

Comment: Yes, someone who reed tag :) And if I don't want to skip Empty Part ?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil that's optional

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a split function.
See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split as reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a standard function in C++. You can use the following approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//,,,


std::istringstream is( line );
std::vector<std::string> v;

std::string item;
while ( std::getline( is, item, ';' ) ) v.push_back( item );
```